# C# Microsoft Report from datatable object

Tags: c#, datatable, report

I would like to use the Microsoft Report Viewer component to view a report created from a programatically filled datatable.

I have been looking for a while but the only information I can find is for reporting on information from a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do that - if you programmatically control the Report viewer control (in Winforms or ASP.NET).

See these resources for some help and guidance:

- [MSDN: Creating Data Sources for a Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252094.aspx)
- [ReportViewer Set DataTable as DataSource (VB.NET)](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=166037)

Answer (score 0):

you can use visual studio to create and then deploy your report. After having created a project for Microsoft Reporting Server, you should add a datasource to it (this is to say where u want to connect to), then open report data view where you can create a query. This allow u to drag & drop fields on your report.

Hope this was what u intended to